# Show equal cardinality between $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ and $\{(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:n\leq m\}$

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Can someone let me know if the below proof is OK and/or needs work? Are piecewise functions appropriate in these situations or was there a better approach?

> Show whether the two given sets have equal cardinality by describing a bijection from one to the other. Consider the set $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:n\leq m\}$.

My answer:

Define $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:n\leq m\}$ as $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ if $x\leq y$ and $f(x,y)=(y,x)$ if $x>y$.

Proof of bijection:

First we will show that $f$ is injective. Let $f(x,y)=f(m,n)$. We will examine two cases.

Case 1. Suppose $x\leq y$. Then $f(x,y)=f(m,n)$ becomes $(x,y)=(m,n)$.

Case 2. Suppose $x>y$. Then $f(x,y)=f(m,n)$ becomes $(y,x)=(n,m)$.

In either case our ordered pairs are equal, thus $f$ is injective.

Now, we will show that $f$ is surjective. Suppose $b=(r,s)\in\{(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:n\leq m\}$, then $f(r,s)=b$.

Since our function is injective and surjective it follows that $f$ is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\land\{(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:n\leq m\}$. Therefore $\vert\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\vert=\vert\{(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:n\leq m\}\vert$. $\Box$

Comment: For a bijection, consider $$(n,m)\mapsto(n,m-n+1)$$

Comment: @Did Would the bijection not be $(n,m)\rightarrow (n,m+n+1)$ instead? Doesn't the function you gave here cause $m$ to always be less than $n$?

Comment: The bijection in my comment is defined on the set of $(n,m)$ in $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ such that $n\leqslant m$, with values in $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. The reverse mapping (which you might be alluding to in your comment) is $(n,m)\mapsto(n,n+m-1)$, not $(n,m)\mapsto(n,n+m+1)$.

Comment: If $n=m=1$ then $(n,m-n+1)=(1,-1)$, you say? Are you really absolutely completely sure about that?

Comment: @Did Yes I just removed my comment. Oy vey. Long day :).

Answer (score 1):

Your function $f$ is obviously not injective: $f(1,2) = (1,2) = f(2,1)$.

In your proof, you failed to consider the case that $x < y$ and $m \geq n$.

For a better idea, try drawing a picture of $S = \{(n,m)\mid n\leq m\}$ as a subset of the grid $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$, and think about how you could line up the full grid with $S$. Hint: shift rows.